# Creating Indexes to optimize query

Tags: oracle, index, query, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have this query and I want to increase its performance by adding appropriate Indexes.

```
DELETE 
  FROM MYTAB1 
  WHERE MYID1 IN 
        ( SELECT MYID2 FROM MYTAB2 );
```

I am not familiar with the syntax for indices and the type of settings that they require. Please provide the same.

The main issue here is that `MYTAB1` has millions of records and thus the query takes a lot of time.

What indices do I need?

Comment: what indexes do you have on MYTAB1 and MYTAB2? This is difficult to answer without more information on the table structure

Comment: there are indexes on other columns but not on these columns

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help.  If your data looks something like this:

```
create table mytab1 as (select level myid1 from dual connect by level <=2000000);
create table mytab2 as (select level+20000 myid2 from dual connect by level <=100);
```

No indexes:

> Cost: 881, Consistent Gets: 3140, CPU Used: 174

Index on MyTab1 Table:

```
create index myid1_1 on mytab1 (myid1);
```

> Cost: 104, Consistent Gets: 103, CPU Used: 14

Index on both MyTab1 and MyTab2:

```
create index myid2_1 on mytab2 (myid2);
```

> Cost: 53, Consistent Gets: 102, CPU Used: 12

Your mileage will vary depending on quite a few factors, but in general an index on myid1 would probably be beneficial.

If you haven't already you should read through the Oracle [Concepts Guide (pdf)](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_pdf?pathname=server.112/e25789.pdf) particularly the section on indexing.

Comment: Also partitioning may help.